# Matching line of result plus two following lines?

Tags: regex

Could you please help me out on this one?
I am running

```
`regEx = new RegExp(`(^.*${searchterm}.*\n?(.*))\n?`, "gm")`
```

to match the line containing the "searchterm" and the line below that.
Now I need to capture an additional line below that, so first the line containing the match and the two following full lines.
How would one modify the RegExp?

Since the solution makes the script crash, here is the full script:

```
<script>
        function parse(e) {
            const dataInput = document.getElementById("data").value;
            const searchtermInput = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;

            const searchterm = searchtermInput.split(",").map(s => s.trim());

            result.innerHTML = "";
            searchterm.forEach((searchterm, i) => {
                const regEx = new RegExp(`^.*${searchterm(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}.*(?:\n.*){0,2}`, "gm");
                let match = regEx.exec(dataInput);
                while(match != null) {
                    console.log("match", match);
                    result.innerHTML += `
                        <li>
                            <p>${match[1].replace(searchterm, '<strong>'+ searchterm +'</strong>')}</p>
                            <p>${match[2]}</p>
                        </li>
                    `;
                    match = regEx.exec(dataInput);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
regEx = new RegExp(`^.*${searchterm.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}.*(?:\n.*){0,2}`, "gm")
```

Or, if you need to capture the three values separately,

```js
regEx = new RegExp(`^(.*${searchterm.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}.*)(?:\n(.*))?(?:\n(.*))?`, "gm")
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `.*` - any chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `${searchterm.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}` - an escaped `searchterm` variable
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n.*){0,2}` - zero, one or two lines.

Comment: That seems to break my script. It stops searching the input and just refreshes.

Comment: @RolandR88 Then show the script. Add it to the question.

Comment: @RolandR88 I added a variation that captures one, two or three lines in separate groups.

Comment: Thanks, since it still crashes, I added the full script

Comment: @RolandR88 Your script requires two groups. So, what are they? Group 1: with the search term, and Group 2: one or two lines below? If yes, use ``regEx = new RegExp(`^(.*${searchterm.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')}.*)((?:\n.*){0,2})`, "gm")``